# Require assistance with coding a word guess game in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a word guess game which looks like [this](https://youtu.be/W-IJcC4tYFI).

I have created the bootstrap divs that will hold the info of my code and declared some variables, but I am now stuck.

*Disclaimer: I am quite new to programming!*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Word Guess Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="artist row">
    </div>
    <div class="gamearea row">
      <div class="albumarea col-6">
      </div>
      <div class="actualgame col-6">
        <div class="startarea">
          <p id="start-text">Press any key to start playing!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="winsarea">
          <p id="wins-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="current-wordarea">
          <p id="currentword-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="remaining-guessesarea">
          <p id="guessremaining-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="letters-guessedarea">
          <p id="letterguessed-text"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="starts"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var wins = 0;
    var currentword = 0;

    var letter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

    var Word = ["marley", "babyface", "hamilton"];
    var solution = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)]
    var solutionlength = solution.length;
    var display = [solutionlength];
    var lettersguessed = solution.split("");
    var guessesremaining = 12;
    var output = "";
    var win = solutionlength
    var letterplayed = "";

    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
      var userGuess = event.key;
      if () {

      }
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you maybe help us understand what you're stuck on or what the problem is?

Comment: I'm stuck like you see in the code. I'm stuck  at the bottom. I don't know how to continue. If you run the code, it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to explain WHAT doesn't work. You'll have a hard time finding help at this rate.

Comment: I would like the code create the game as this on youtube:  https://youtu.be/W-IJcC4tYFI . But I don't know what to do after declaring my variable.

Comment: This website isn't made for you to give an empty `if` and ask people to fill it in. Please create a [Minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a problem and post another question. Until you can get to that point you should do some tutorials to learn javascript

Comment: Well my question is not fill in the empty if. Please to read my question very well which you did not the first time you asked your question. I need assistance doesn't mean I want you to do the problem for me sir. I need the step from someone who wants to take time to assist. Please I really need help and there are other people out there who, once were just like me. They didn't know what to do and needed help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the first-step would be to confirm the code you have so-far.

For myself, I have stepped through it and can see a few problems.

The first is the variable `Word` is referenced as `word` on the next
line. Make sure the case (UPPER/lower) of your variables always match.

Next, it looks like `display` is supposed to be an empty-array that has
an initial-length as specified by `solutionlength`. But array-literal
syntax `[]` will just make `solutionlength` the first-item in your array.
Use `var display = new Array(solutionlength);` to create an empty-array
with the size `solutionlength`.

Under that, `lettersguessed` is either wrongly named or wrongly 
initialised. It should be called `letters_in_the_solution`, for example.
Or it should be initialised to an empty-array to store the guesses of
the player.

Those are the main issues, but there is also some general confusion
about the intent of the variables. For example, you declare 
`currentword`, but don't use it in initialising `solution`. Instead, you initialise directly using the Math... stuff.

Anyway, rather than completely filling-in your `if` statement, I'll
outline what a `draw()` method could potentially look like in pseudo-
code:

```
when user presses a key ->
    add the key to an array called letters_guessed
    set a variable called is_solved to true

    now loop through all the letters in the solution ->
        does the current letter exist in letters_guessed?
            yes -> 
                draw the current letter
            no -> 
                draw an underbar _
                and set the variable called is_solved to false

    is the variable is_solved set to true?
        yes ->
            win += 1
            generate a new word
            clear the letters_guessed array
        no ->
            do nothing
```

It's generally a good practice to outline your code as a simple specification like this before jumping-in to write stuff if you're not sure what to write.

You can start off with a more simple outline than this, and gradually make it more and more code-like until you think you can express the whole thing as real code.

Hope it's helpful.